# How to get the difference between two timestamps in minutes?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Demo

```
create table my_table (ts1 timestamp,ts2 timestamp);

insert into my_table (ts1,ts2) values 
    (timestamp '2017-01-29 07:35:14.52',timestamp '2017-01-29 15:01:59.14');
```

I'm familiar with the following method:

```
select  (   extract (day    from (ts2-ts1))*24*60*60
        +   extract (hour   from (ts2-ts1))*60*60
        +   extract (minute from (ts2-ts1))*60
        +   extract (second from (ts2-ts1))
    )/60  as ts_diff_minutes

from    my_table
;
```

---

```
+------------------------------------------+
| TS_DIFF_MINUTES                          |
+------------------------------------------+
| 446.743666666666666666666666666666666667 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I was wondering if there is a shorter version to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you give an example of the source (timestamp) and the result (extracted minutes)? It's not exactly clear what you mean by "extracting minutes from timestamp".

Comment: Hello @mustaccio, I edited the variables and just replaced it with systimestamp. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I'm afraid this doesn't help a bit, because that's not an example. I'd expect an example to be something like: "I have the timestamp '2017-02-01 20:59:08', and I want the result to be 59, because it's 59 minutes since the latest full hour". Replace the logic with what _you_ need.

Comment: I edited it once more. Let's say the time is `05:04:02` and I'd like to get the 04 minutes part of the timestamp.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Doesn't just `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)` return what you want?

Comment: @JSapkota, that's what my original code looked like with my named variables, I sadly forgot to put it back after replacing my variables to primitive `systimestamp`.as requested for easier comprehension.  The main purpose is still to find a shorter way of extracting minutes, after doing subtraction between two timestamps. I hope I make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching over the internet, I was able to find a shorter version of the code that I was asking for. After several attempts of deriving the code I found [here](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2010/10/20/difference-between-two-timestamps/).

`(CAST((SYSTIMESTAMP + interval '35' minute) as date) - CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP as date)) * 1440`

**Result:** 

`+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
|     35 |
+--------+`

This version is faster compared to the version that uses EXTRACT. The only downside of this version is that it doesn't include fractions of a second.